# Getting value from Excel cell with formula via openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I need to get value from Excel cell with formula, but I don't need formula. I need a **value**, but not the formula from cell. How can I do it? I tried using just

```py
working_sheet.cell(row=row_number, column=column_number+1).value
```

and extending a list. But I getting list like

```
[
    '2020',
    'остальные грузы',
    'КОЛУМБИЯ',
    'НОВ.ПОРТ-ЭКС',
    'НОВ.ПОРТ-ЭКС',
    'НОВ.ПОРТ-ЭКС',
    'НОВ.ПОРТ-ЭКС',
    'МЕКСИКА',
    'повагонная',
    'порожние',
    '0',
    '0',
    '=VLOOKUP(C28038,$AB$2:$AC$1048576,2,FALSE)', 
    '=VLOOKUP(H28038,$AB$2:$AC$1048576,2,FALSE)',
    '=VLOOKUP(E28038,$X$2:$Y$1048576,2,FALSE)',
    '=VLOOKUP(F28038,$X$2:$Y$1048576,2,FALSE)'
]
```

so i don't need for values like `=VLOOKUP...`

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are using [`data_only=True`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) when loading the workbook:

```py
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
worksheet = workbook.active  # active worksheet

print(worksheet.cell(column=10, row=5).value)
```

Be aware: Excel stores evaluated values in the file. That said, these values are only available if the file was opened with Excel (or *maybe* with a similar application) before.